# How to synchronously wait for reply block when using NSXPCConnection

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, xpc, nsxpcconnection

I'm using NSXPCConnection and one of my interface call has a reply block, like this:

```
- (void)addItem:(NSData *) withLabel:(NSString *) reply:(void (^)(NSInteger rc))reply;
```

Which I call like this:

```
__block NSInteger status;
[proxy addItem:data withLabel:@"label" reply:^(NSInteger rc)
         {
             status = rc;
         }
];
```

My understanding is that the reply block run asynchronously, and potentially after the method returns.

I want to test the return code synchronously, what's the best way to do it?

---

To clarify further the snippet above: the `proxy` object is the remote object obtained from an `NSXPCConnection` object using the `remoteObjectProxy` method. This is an important detail as this impact on which queue the reply block is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose to use dispatch_semaphore.

```
// Create it before the block:
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
__block NSInteger status = 0;
[proxy addItem:data withLabel:@"label" reply:^(NSInteger rc) {
             status = rc;
             // In the block you signal the semaphore:
             dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
         }
];

// here wait for signal
// I dont remember exactly function prototype, but you should specify here semaphore and the time waiting (INFINITE)
dispatch_semaphore_wait(...);

// in non-ARC environment dont forget to release semaphore
dispatch_release(semaphore);

return status;
```

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing (more or less)

Answer (score 13):

I just found out a probably better way to do this:

Use `synchronousRemoteObjectProxyWithErrorHandler` instead of `remoteObjectProxy` when creating the remote object.

No need for semaphore or group.

Comment: how did you define your methods? even after trying this I continue to get 
* Return type of methods sent over this proxy must be 'void'*

Answer (score 5):

This is what dispatch groups were made for.

```
NSTimeInterval timeout = 120; // in seconds
__block NSInteger status;

dispatch_group_t syncGroup = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_enter(syncGroup);

[proxy addItem:data withLabel:@"label" reply:^(NSInteger rc)
    {
        status = rc;
        dispatch_group_leave(syncGroup);
    }
];

dispatch_time_t waitTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(NSEC_PER_SEC * timeout));

if(dispatch_group_wait(syncGroup, waitTime) != 0)
{
    // complain about a request timing out
}

// enjoy your status
```

if you chose to use remoteObjectProxyWithErrorHandler to get your proxy, then you need to remember to also put a call to dispatch_group_leave(syncGroup) in your error handler.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to test the return code synchronously, what's the best way to
>   do it?

You really don't want it to run synchronously.  That'll just block the queue/thread that the block is running on and generally cause havoc to crashes.

Instead, after the `status = rc;` line, make a call to something that can process the fact that it is done.    Let the method return, let the queue or event loop run, then do the work needed whenever `addItem:withLabel:` is done.

---

Like this:

```
__block NSInteger status;
[proxy addItem:data withLabel:@"label" reply:^(NSInteger rc) {
             status = rc;
             // like this ...
             [someObject processReturnedStatus];
         }
];
```

Comment: The method that is calling this code is supposed to return the status code, and I don't really have a choice: that's an interface that is not under my control.